# How to access MacOS SDK in electron project, such as PortSIPSDK.framework

Tags: macos, sdk, electron

In the electron project, I want to use MacOS sdk, I don't know how to package it

I try "nodobjc", but it's too old to run. Is there any other library that allows me to directly call the sdk of MacOS?

I can call oc functions in the node environment now. node-addon-api ,c++ -> c -> oc， node-gyp build addon, main.js require(addon).but I don't know how to call the oc SDK. Is there a demo?